# Ayuda con objeto en js acceder a propiedades

Tags: javascript, objeto

Normalmente accedo a las propiedades de los objetos asi:

```
nombre = body.first_name;
```

El problema es que la ruta la recibo por parametro.

```
var ruta="first_name"
```

y al poner

```
nombre= body.ruta;
```

intenta acceder a la propiedad ruta y no a la propiedad first_name

Comment: No está muy claro lo que pretendes... `body.ruta` no tiene nada que ver con `var ruta`. Si quieres guardar el `firstname` tienes que poner `body.firstname = "firstname"` y despues acceder de igual manera.

Comment: quiero recibir la ruta desde un string. un ejemplo mas completo seria:

Comment: var path = "user.extended.first_name";
  texto= body.path;

Comment: pero en ese caso accederia a body.path y no a body.user.extended.first_name

Comment: Ahhh entonces en la ruta te indica qué propiedad quieres acceder. no ¿?

Comment: si asi mismo, pero si pongo eso accede a la propiedad con ese nombre y no a la propiedad que tengo guardada en la ruta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para acceder a una propiedad basta acceder mediante los brackets `[` `]`, el operador debe ser un texto

Por ejemplo

```js
var obj = {first_name: "Jhon Doe"}
var ruta="first_name"
nombre = obj[ruta] 
console.log(nombre)
```

La línea `obj[ruta]` se expande a `obj["first_name"]` que es equivalente a hacer `obj.first_name` por lo tanto devuelve `Jhon doe`

Comment: var path = "user.extended.first_name";
      divide = body[path];

Comment: probe asi y no puedo acceder

Comment: en cambio divide= body.user.extended.first_name;

Comment: si funciona. no logro pasarle por variable

Comment: @AlexisGranja eso es porque no es recursivo, debes hacer en todo caso un eval, ya que tienes muchos objetos anidados `var nombre = eval('body.' +ruta)` ó bien hacer una función que acceda recursivamente a las propiedades...

Answer (score 3):

Las otras soluciones lo mas seguro es que fallen cuando se intenta acceder a un `nested object`, es decir, un objeto mas complejo que tenga otro objeto dentro, y queramos acceeder a una pripiedad que esta bien adentro, pues bien, hice una pequena funcion utilitaria que puede ayudar a resolver este problema:

```js
function getProps(obj, path) {
  var arr = path.split('.');
  var parent = obj;
  var name = arr[0];

  arr.slice(1).forEach((fieldName) => {
    parent[name] = parent[name] || {};
    parent = parent[name];
    name = fieldName;
  });
  return parent[name];
}


var obj = {
  bar: {
    foo: 3,
    hello: {
      there: {
        foo: 3
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(getProps(obj, 'bar.foo'));
console.log(getProps(obj, 'bar.hello.there'));
```

## Update

Dejo el ejemplo completo de como lo uso, del cual lo adapte para la respuesta, este es mas completo pues tambien puede modificar el json, y crear los campos padres como sea necesario:

```
export function resolvePath(obj: any, path: string) {
    const arr = path.split(".");
    let parent = obj;
    let name = arr[0];

    arr.slice(1).forEach((fieldName) => {
        parent[name] = parent[name] || {};
        parent = parent[name];
        name = fieldName;
    });

    return {
        get(): any {
            return parent[name];
        },
        set(value: any) {
            parent[name] = value;
        },
        delete() {
            delete parent[name];
        },
        ref() {
            return [parent, name];
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: y por qué no usar `eval()` directamente?

Comment: Se podria, pero no es estrictamente javascript, y no te sabria decir por que pero en todas las documentaciones que he leido siempre desconsejan usar eval por motivos de seguridad.

Comment: Dejo algunos links de una busqueda rapida sobre este tema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil , https://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval , pero en ingles :|

Answer (score 2):

Tambien se puede usar lodash.get https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get. Del ejemplo de este link:

```js
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
 
console.log(_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c'));
// => 3
 
console.log(_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']));
// => 3
 
console.log(_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default'));
// => 'default'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que tu objeto Body es así

```
function Body(){

 this.first_name = "Alexis";


}
```

Puedes acceder a esa propiedad `first_name` directamente

```js
function Body() {

  this.first_name = "Alexis";


}

var body = new Body();

console.log(body.first_name);
```

O también puedes pasar el `string` que contenga la propiedad que quieras.

```
body["first_name"]
```

Si sabes que la ruta te va a llegar del formato `user.extended.propiedad` puedes hacer un `split(".")` y quedarte el ultimo elemento

```js
function Body() {

  this.first_name = "Alexis";


}

var body = new Body();


var ruta =  "user.extended.first_name";

var propiedad = ruta.split(".")[2];

console.log(body[propiedad]);
```

Comment: divide = body.user.extended.first_name;

Comment: asi si puedo acceder

Comment: y pruebo con      var path = "user.extended.first_name";
                          divide = body[path];

Comment: y no funciona ....

Comment: claro porque tu `path` no es directabmente `body.first_name`. Si sabes qué formato va a tener el path puedes hacer un `substring` para coger la parte que te interesa, en este caso el ultimo `first_name`. @AlexisGranja (y no escribas tantos comentarios...)

Comment: no tengo idea de como va a llegar el path. puede tener pocos o varios elementos

Comment: tienes que saber como te va a llegar ... para poder actuar acorde... @alexis. edité la respuesta para que veas a que me refiero

Comment: gracias por la ayuda ya lo consegui